# Has T. D. Jakes clarified what he believes about the Trinity?

Tags: trinity, oneness-pentecostalism

[T. D. Jakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T._D._Jakes) is a popular American pastor and speaker who was ordained within [Oneness Pentecostalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oneness_Pentecostalism), a modern [modalist group](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/33133/6071) which denies the Trinity.

Jakes has in recent times moved towards Trinitarian Christianity. Wikipedia [records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T._D._Jakes#Beliefs) that in 2012 he affirmed the trinity, but "did not affirm the eternality of the individual persons."

Jakes has been invited to popular Protestant events such as the Hillsong Conference. His lack of clarity on whether he fully endorses the doctrine of the Trinity has concerned many people (and led them to say that his conference hosts have lacked discernment.)

Has Jakes clarified since 2012 whether or not he fully endorses and believes in the Trinity as defined in the Nicene, Athanasian, and/or Chalcedonian creeds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It seems that as of this writing (May 2017) his last attempt to publicly clarify his doctrine of God was the 2012 interview you refer to. If you [Google some combination of TD Jakes trinity](https://www.google.com/search?q=td%20jakes%20trinity), you'll only find discussions of that interview, or of [his 2000 *Christianity Today* article](http://www.christianitytoday.com/ct/2000/februaryweb-only/13.0b.html), or of his affiliations with Oneness Pentecostalism.

The 2012 interview in question sparked a major controversy in the reformed evangelical blogosphere, with the general consensus (as represented in [Justin Taylor's write-up](https://blogs.thegospelcoalition.org/justintaylor/2012/02/01/the-elephant-room-what-really-happened-and-how-things-could-have-been-different/)) being that the interview itself was a mistake and that nothing had truly been clarified. A [2014 blog post by reformed Baptist Tim Challies](https://www.challies.com/articles/the-false-teachers-t-d-jakes) (generally a good researcher) indicates no knowledge of any post-2012 trinitarian confession by Jakes. Jakes' [church's belief statement](http://thepottershouse.org/explore/belief-statement/), while not explicitly modalist, still shies away from trinitarian credal language and retains the use of the favored modalist term "manifestations" instead of "persons" to describe the Godhead. He is also [vice-prelate of Higher Ground Always Abounding Assemblies](http://www.highergroundaaa.com/about-us), which is [allegedly a Oneness Pentecostal organization](http://www.donotbesurprised.com/2012/06/vice-prelate-td-jakes-to-speak-at-holy.html).

Answer (score 0):

He has stated a revision of his view, as of January 2012, that he now accepts the orthodox view of the Trinity. This would be the view promulgated at IV. Lateran (the 12th Ecumenical Council):

> “I began to realize that there are some things that could be said about the Father that could not be said about the Son,” Jakes said. “There are distinctives between the working of the Holy Spirit and the moving of the Holy Spirit, and the working of the redemptive work of Christ. I’m very comfortable with that.” — T.D. Jakes

Now how prepared he is to make a statement of orthodox faith, well - that's anyone's guess.

But yes, he has given some clarification on the matter.

[Further reading here](http://apprising.org/2012/01/25/elephant-room-2-may-we-now-regard-t-d-jakes-as-trinitarian-and-orthodox/).

Comment: That looks to be the same conversation which he had with Driscoll and MacDonald which Wikipedia was describing. I was specifically asking if he had clarified what he believed since then, and whether he fully endorses the Nicene, Athanasian or Chalcedonian creeds.

Comment: I was unable to find anything of that sort. So I would guess 'no'.

Comment: @Russell That last comment should be [edit]ed into your post as that's what really answers this question at this point.